# What animation during a view controller presentation will be used by UIKit if modalPresentationStyle is set to .custom

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, transition

For example i have a custom transitioning delegate with only 1 method implemented:

```
class CustomTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    
    func presentationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController?, source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        let presentationController = CustomTransitionPresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presenting: presenting)

        return presentationController
    }
}
```

and then has set only `modalPresentationStyle = .custom` of a view controller and `transitioningDelegate = ourCustomTransitionWithoutAnyAnimator`

So what type of animation will be used?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify the Delegate to conform for ourCustomTransitionWithoutAnyAnimator inside the viewcontroller, otherwise it will fall into the case below:

It will use whatever the presentingViewController conforming UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate and return its own custom presenting animations
as in your case it returns: CustomTransitionPresentationController.

- Your CustomTransitionPresentationController could be conforming UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and have the following methods for customisations:

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {}

- Or a subclass of UIPresentationController